# Execute something which takes 5 seconds (like email send) but return with response immediately?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, asynchronous, background, fire-and-forget

**Context**

In an ASP.NET Core application I would like to execute an operation which takes say 5 seconds (like sending email). I do know async/await and its purpose in ASP.NET Core, however I do not want to wait the end of the operation, instead I would like to return back to the to the client immediately.

**Issue**

So it is kinda Fire and Forget either homebrew, either Hangfire's `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IEmailSender>(x => x.Send("hangfire@example.com"));`

Suppose I have some more complex method with injected ILogger and other stuff and I would like to Fire and Forget that method. In the method there are error handling and logging.(note: not necessary with Hangfire, the issue is agnostic to how the background worker is implemented). My problem is **that method will run completely out of context**, probably nothing will work inside, no HttpContext (I mean HttpContextAccessor will give null etc) so no User, no Session etc.

**Question**

How to correctly solve say this particular email sending problem? No one wants wait with the response 5 seconds, and the same time no one wants to throw and email, and not even logging if the send operation returned with error...

Comment: So, why not just use Hangfire then?

Comment: ...please reread the bold text, then the question...

Comment: OK.... Hangfire doesn't need an HttpContext

Comment: It is me, who need httpcontext, for example to know who the user is, etc. Also using transient and scoped instances, those all turn nonsense when using out of context

Comment: Then wrap up that data into an object and pass it to Hangfire. There is no other safe way since the context will be disposed of when the HTTP request is done.

Comment: does [this](https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/10/14/fire-and-forget-in-aspnet-core-with-dependency-alive) help ? I use this daily, and seems no problem so far (ofcourse, no `HttpContext` available in this approach)

Comment: Many thx. At least I know i am not alone :-) Now I realize there is no universal solution, but as a minimum the logging (with the injected ILogger) should work.

Answer (score 0):

> How to correctly solve say this particular email sending problem?

This is a specific instance of the "run a background job from my web app" problem.

> there is no universal solution

There is - or at least, a universal *pattern*; it's just that many developers try to avoid it because it's not easy.

I describe it pretty fully in my blog post series on the [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html). I think one important thing to acknowledge is that since your background work (sending an email) is done outside of an HTTP request, it really should be done outside of your web app process. Once you accept that, the rest of the solution falls into place:

1. You need a durable storage queue for the work. Hangfire uses your database; I tend to prefer cloud queues like Azure Storage Queues.
2. This means you'll need to copy all the data over that you will need, since it needs to be serialized into that queue. The same restriction applies to Hangfire, it's just not obvious because Hangfire runs in the same web application process.
3. You need a background process to execute your work queue. I tend to prefer Azure Functions, but another common approach is to run an [ASP.NET Core Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) as a Win32 service or Linux daemon. Hangfire has its own ad-hoc in-process thread. Running an ASP.NET Core hosted service in-process would also work, though that has some of the same drawbacks as Hangfire since it also runs in the web application process.
4. Finally, your work queue processor application has its own service injection, and you can code it to [create a dependency scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service) per work queue item if desired.

IMO, this is a normal threshold that's reached as your web application "grows up". It's more complex than a simple web app: now you have a web app, a durable queue, and a background processor. So your deployment becomes more complex, you need to think about things like versioning your worker queue schema so you can upgrade without downtime (something Hangfire can't handle well), etc. And some devs really balk at this because it's more complex when "all" they want to do is send an email without waiting for it, but the fact is that this is the necessary step upwards when a baby web app becomes distributed.